# How to display complex pricing for mentorship platform

Tags: design, product-design, product-management, product

I have an issue with my UI. I run a mentorship platform that charges $19.99/month and then users can book calls with mentors. Some mentors do not charge an additional fee so the cost is $0/call. However, when the user goes to the landing page, they see $0/call and thing it's fake or not aware of the membership fee. How can I fix my UI so that the membership fee is clearer to users? I don't want to deceive them. Here's the page - https://www.mentordial.com/

Comment: Why don't you write "Free for members" in this case? ux.stackexchange is a question site about user experience and does not deal with technical implementation. So if you have a problems with that, you might have more success at stackoverflow.

Comment: There's something wrong with how this model works. Users don't like added or hidden fees to subscriptions. Why not have tiers? Like Regular member subscription starting at $19.99/month for $0 mentors, Pro member subscription starting at $24.99 for the more expensive mentors.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be to clearly display the membership fee on the landing page, either in the main call-to-action for the platform or in a prominent location nearby. Saying something like "$19.99/month + applicable per-call fees (from $0)". This could help to ensure that users are aware of the $19.99/month fee and the potential of paying nothing per call, before they begin interacting with the platform and booking calls with mentors.

Another approach could be to include information about the membership fee and the cost of individual calls in the booking flow, before the user is asked to confirm their booking or using difference sections in the landing-page flow. Something like: $19.99/month as the main price, then individual sections for free calls and calls that cost an additional fee. This would allow you to provide more detailed information about the fees and charges associated with using the platform, and give users the opportunity to review and understand the costs before committing to a booking.

Additionally, you could consider adding a disclaimer or notice on the landing page that clarifies the membership fee and the cost of individual calls. This could help to prevent users from misunderstanding the pricing and avoid any potential issues with deceptive advertising. A sub-header under your pricing section would be a good implementation.

Overall, the key is to be clear and transparent.